# Check if link is metered using `ip`

Tags: ip

Is it possible to find out whether an interface is sending/receiving packets using a metered link only using `/usr/bin/ip`? I have seen [two solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43228973/1582182) using `NetworkManager` with `nmcli` or `dbus` but I am not using this tool. Is there some other tool that can detect it?

Comment: metered / unmetered is not something that is quantifiable on the hardware, it's simply a concept that networkmanager can assign to an interface. As such it's a property of networkmanager and not of the interface itself. The kernel has no information about this.

Comment: @wurtel Thanks! What about the second part of the question. It seems `NetworkManager` is able to *guess* whether a link is metered.
Is there some other tool than `NetworkManager` to do this?

Comment: I have not much experience with NetworkManager, but I know you can set this property manually on an interface. Besides that, probably any dialup connection using a 4G dongle or similar is assumed to be metered. A reference I found states "Specifically Bluetooth PAN/DUN setup and falls back to checking whether the device is a modem"